# How to Save a Fragment with user progress

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem when i play a soundfile and i go to another fragment and back to the first fragment it show me that is not playing but the soundfile is playing and if i tape again on soundfile it play over the first sound and i hope that someone have a solution for me because i been search all over internet and I'm new to android Studio

```
ImageButton test1 ;
Button test10;
FrameLayout framelayout ;
SeekBar  volumeBar;
MediaPlayer mp,pm;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

    

  test1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.test);
    test10 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.test10);
    framelayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
 //   pm = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lofistudy);
//    mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
    pm = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.lofistudy);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.lightrain);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    pm.setLooping(true);

    //volume bar
     volumeBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.volumeBar);
 volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    float volumeNum =  progress / 100f;
                    mp.setVolume(volumeNum, volumeNum);
                    pm.setVolume(volumeNum, volumeNum);
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            }
    );


    test1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadFragment(new detailFragment());
            if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                loadFragment(new detailFragment());
                // Stopping
                mp.start();
                test1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop23);
                volumeBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        volumeBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 5000);

            } else {
                // Playing
                mp.pause();
                test1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop2);

            }
        }
    });

    test10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadFragment(new detailFragment());
            if (!pm.isPlaying()) {
                loadFragment(new detailFragment());
                // Stopping
                pm.start();

                volumeBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        volumeBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 5000);

            } else {
                // Playing
                pm.pause();


            }
        }
    });

return rootView ;
}
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //replace the fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want to play in the background:**
You should call `mediaPlayer.pause()` on `onPause()` of the fragment and `mediaPlayer.play()` on `onResume()` of the fragment.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#state-diagram) for more understanding.